# How do I access a outer class variables and functions from an inner class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm a beginner in python and I've been wondering how can I access an outer class from an inner one

I know I might be asking the wrong way but I would be thankful if you helped me.

see the example

```
class big_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.big_var = "a variable"
    
    def func(self):
        print("a big  function")

    class small_class:
        def __init__(self):
            # I don't know how to access big_var or func() from here
```

If I made a mistake please let me know so I can edit the question.

Comment: nested classes is not the same as parent/child classes.

Comment: Refer to it as `big_class.big_var`.

Comment: Why are you nesting classes? Note, that is *not* what is meant by parent/child class. Generally, nesting classes is not commonly done in Python. In any case, `big_var` is a *local variable* to the `__init__` method in `big_class`, there is no way to access it outside of that method.

Comment: `func` is an instance method, so to access it in `small_class`, you need to use some reference to an instance, usually, you would pass this instance as an argument to `small_class.__init__`. Again, all of this really has nothing to do with your classes being nested, which is very unidiomatic and doesn't really do anything for you here